# Get records which are not present in join table

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, left-join

I have three tables in MySQL database. First table contains users, second table contains items. Below is the structure of those two.

```
users
------
userid (int)
username (varchar)

items
------
itemid (int)
name (varchar)
```

The third table is a join table.

```
user_items
----------
userid (int)
itemid (int)
```

I would like to have a query which returns me the list of users and the items not assigned to them.

In example
I have following users

```
userid      username
1           john
2           tim
3           mark
```

Also I have following items

```
itemid      name
1           book
2           pen
3           backpack
```

In the join table I have

```
userid    itemid
1         1
1         3
2         1
2         2
2         3
3         2
```

As a result I would like to have list of items not owned by users, like:

```
userid    itemid
1         2
3         1
3         3
```

What would be the best query to get such result. I am trying with some left joins, left outer joins, not in etc. but without success.

Edit 1:
I have tried so far with following query:

```sql
SELECT con.userid, i.itemid FROM items i
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT u.id as userid, ui.itemid
FROM users u
INNER JOIN user_items ui ON u.userid = ui.itemid
) con ON i.itemid = con.itemid
WHERE con.itemid IS NULL
```

Comment: The OUTER keyword is optional, i.e. LEFT JOIN is the same as LEFT OUTER JOIN. Can  you show us your attempt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As a result I would like to have list of items not owned by users

You would typically `cross join` the users and products to generate all possible combinations, then filter out associations that already exist in the bridge table:

```
select u.userid, p.itemid
from users u
cross join items i
where not exists (
    select 1 from user_items ui where ui.userid = u.userid and ui.itemid = i.itemid
)
```

For performance, you want an inde on `user_items(userid, itemid)` (it should already be there if you have a `unique` constraints on these columns).

We could also express the logic with a anti-`left join`:

```
select u.userid, p.itemid
from users u
cross join items i
left join user_items ui on ui.userid = u.userid and ui.itemid = i.itemid
where ui.userid is null
```